# C++ Windows - Resizing ListView with window

Tags: c++, windows, listview

Right now I am resizing my ListView when a window recieve WM_SIZING message like that:

```
    if (message == WM_SIZING)
    {
        RECT A;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &A);
        SetWindowPos(ListView, 0, 0, 0, A.right, A.bottom, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }
```

That resize ListView as expected, over whole client area.
However resizing visualy isn't so nice (there is slight delay between ListView and window). I understand  the cause of that delay (because I'm getting client area before window has been resized). Message SIZING doesn't contain info of client area that I could just use.
Is there any other message that I could handle and achieve nicer resizing?

Comment: In addition to utilizing the info provided for your sizing, you may also consider whether the *parent* of this window is doing things like setting up a null background brush and  handling `WM_ERASEBKGND` to squelch background painting of the parent client area, which is an utter waste of time if you're overlaying the entire thing with a child control.

Comment: The `lParam` of the `WM_SIZING` message tells you the proposed size of the window. Use that to determine the size of your listview.

Comment: Like I said it does not contain size of client area, but window RECT. Right now I tried handling WM_SIZE which contain client area, but that lag is still present.

Comment: Flicker-free resizing on Windows is **hard**.